# jQuery autocomplete to follow a link on keyboard and mouse click

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have the following jQuery function for autocompleting one of the input fields:

```
  $(function() {
    var url = MyAutocomplete.url + "?action=my_search" 
    $( "#author" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      source: url,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#author" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#author" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#author-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
        $( "#author-description" ).html( ui.item.desc ); 
        return false;
      }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( '<li>' )
        .append( '<a class="user cf" href="'+ item.value +'"><div class="image">' + item.desc + '</div><div class="rightText"><div class="topPart">' + item.label + '</div></div>' )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });
```

It works fine except that it does not follow link straight away. But behabiour is different on mouse and keyboard clicks.

On mouse click: all of the `<li>` items disappear just leaving the `<div class="image">` for a second and only then calls the link.

On keyboard click: it just fills the input field with `item.label`, when expected action is naturally to follow the link.

I am new to jQuery so any help or guidance is much appreciated. If there is any other code that I should have shared, please ask.

**EDIT**

Here is an exampel of HTML of one of the suggestions:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0">
        <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-11" tabindex="-1">
            <a class="user cf" href="http://example.com/user/123">
                <div class="image">
                     <img alt="username" src="http://example/user123.png" class="avatar avatar-32">
                </div>
                <div class="rightText">
                     <div class="topPart">user description</div>
                </div>
            </a>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? What is your HTML looking like?

Comment: @Twisty, thank you for your comment. I have updated the question with html of suggestions sample. 
As for the console, there are no errors provided.

Comment: Where is the Input field in your HTML? For Testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/o0mp2ph9/